# iOS App icon replaced by 'Hack' icon (React Native app)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Seemingly out of nowhere, my app's icon has been replaced by this image I've never seen before. This has only happened on iOS. When I view the AppIcon image in Xcode and the app's target image, it shows the correct icon.

Although I have third-party packages installed, they were already installed prior to this change happening. The app itself seems to still work fine.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

### My best guess

This may have happened after I archived for the first time since rebuilding it. So maybe Xcode thinks I am trying to replicate the old app with the same package name without the correct certification (although I'm using the same App Store Team). My disk is also very full but can't see why that should cause this.

### Similar issues (none)

I haven't been able to find any reference anywhere to something like this happening before - React Native or not. Even the image seems to have been very sparsely used before.

### My temporary fix

I was able to temporarily fix this issue by just changing the name of the app in Xcode and then changing it back. However without archiving since, the issue has reappeared a day later.

### Update

I've done more digging and found the icon is from a sample framework called Iconicus - which I assume was installed by default by React Native. Any ideas on how it's overriding my icon and whether I'm free to delete those sample frameworks please?

[image: Finder screenshot]

My Pod file:

```
pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native/', :subspecs => [
'Core',
'RCTActionSheet',
'RCTGeolocation',
'RCTImage',
'RCTLinkingIOS',
'RCTNetwork',
'RCTSettings',
'RCTText',
'RCTVibration',
'RCTWebSocket',
'DevSupport',
]
pod 'yoga', path: '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

pod 'rn-fetch-blob',
  :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.15.0'
pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.15.0'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.15.0'
pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.15.0'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.13'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'
pod 'NearbyMessages'
pod 'RNTouchThroughView', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-touch-through-view'
pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'


post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

  # The following is needed to ensure the "archive" step works in XCode. It removes React & Yoga from the Pods project, as it is already included in the main project.
  targets_to_ignore = %w(React yoga)

  if targets_to_ignore.include? target.name
    target.remove_from_project
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your pods/carthage dependencies list? What icon is displayed for the app target in Xcode?

Comment: Sure thing @pckill, I've added the info to the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wait, do you recognize this image? Is it from an older version of your app? Did you try deleting derived data? If this did not help, try building the app, extracting the package and checking the app icon. Search your mac for the filename or maybe do an image search.

Comment: Hi @pckill - nope I don't recognise it at all. Never seen it before! Super strange.

Comment: There is a way in iOS to set alternate icons, you can read more about it in this link https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/dynamically-change-the-app-icon-7d4bece820d2 and then look up your plist file to see if it's configured to support alternate app icons

Comment: Thanks @SamuelChavez - interesting insight. Have looked into it though and so such code has been set. However I have found where the image looks to be coming from - please see edited question.

Comment: I am pretty sure you shouldn't include any "Sample" code inside your app.

Comment: It seems this is a sample from FacebookSDK but I don't see it in your pods. Are you including it by some other way? It seems the samples are included by mistake into your app.

Comment: @hardanger A question for you, in the link I sent you there is a short youtube video where they show the functionality for the icon replacement feature, do you see that kind of notification as well? when your icon is changed?

I really don't see what you can do, I looked at the github repo for the sdk but there hasn't been any issued related to an icon replacement:  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk/pulls?page=2&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Hi @Samuel Chavez - hmm interesting thanks for linking, though I didn't get a notification. It looks like Sulthan's comment has resolved the issue, but many thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @Sulthan for suggesting I delete FacebookSDK's sample apps, one of which had this icon. This looks to have fixed the issue (though still unsure how iOS randomly switched app icons).

Comment: I had the same issue, but when I deleted the Samples folder along with all references of Iconicus from my mac, I am left with a share icon. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry to hear that @GeorgeSalamanca. That didn't happen to me so am afraid I can't suggest much, other than to try re-adding your own icon and see if it stays.